# My SKSpriteNode wouldn't show even though I used addChild in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, addchild

I tried to add an image to my Game Scene, but it won't appear. Below is my code. I hope you guys can help me

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
    var iceCream = SKSpriteNode()
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        Ground.setScale(0.5)
        Ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.Ground.frame.height / 2)
        self.addChild(Ground)
        iceCream = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "VanillaIceCream")
        iceCream.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
        iceCream.position = CGPoint(x: self.iceCream.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        self.addChild(iceCream)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is compiling and working fine, do you see any images with an "X" ?

Comment: No. It doesn't appear on my simulator

Comment: The images wouldn't show. I'm not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `position` to`x: self.iceCream.frame.width`
you position it using `iceCream`.
I believe that changing it to `x: self.frame.width / 2` will solve it.
If it is not mistake and you want to set the `iceCream` on the left of the screen, position the `sprite` after adding it to self.
It's also good to set `zPosition` to each element, to make sure it will not hide behind the `background` image.

EDIT:
Here is the full code for your method (ready to copy/paste):

```
Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
self.addChild(Ground)
Ground.setScale(0.5)
Ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
Ground.zPosition = 1.0

iceCream = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "VanillaIceCream")
self.addChild(iceCream)
iceCream.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 70)
iceCream.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
iceCream.zPosition = 2.0
```

Comment: Can you show me an example please for the whole thing including zPosition